# Creating a UIView subclass with optional IBOutlets

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, iboutlet

I am trying to implement a Custom UIView called MediaView.

Inside, I will have a loading indicator by default. On top of it, either an image, a GIF or a video will be shown. Only one IBOutlet will be drawn there.

How can I achieve this?

```
class MediaView: UIView{

@IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator : LoadingActivityIndicator!

@IBOutlet weak var apngImageView : APNGImageView?
@IBOutlet weak var animatedImageView : AnimatedImageView?
@IBOutlet weak var player : Player?

// MARK: - Initializers

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

// MARK: - Private Helper Methods

// Performs the initial setup.
private func setupView() {
    let view = viewFromNibForClass()
    view.frame = bounds

    // Auto-layout stuff.
    view.autoresizingMask = [
        UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
        UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    ]

    // Show the view.
    addSubview(view)
}

// Loads a XIB file into a view and returns this view.
private func viewFromNibForClass() -> UIView {

    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

    return view
}
```

}

Comment: Can't you just set `.isHidden = true` for the two you *don't* want to see, and `.isHidden = false` for the one you *do* want to see?

Comment: I want to just use one of them. Even '.isHidden = true' the object will be alive in the hierarchy.

Comment: ok - then `.removeFromSuperview()`?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you are suggesting that after getting an initializing parameter to indicate the media type in 'func setupView()' I should call '.removeFromSupeview()' for the unnecessary IBOutlets. Did I get that right?

If you see an elegant solution, I can adapt to that too. I just couldn't convince myself to divide 3 different UIView subclasses based on the image type shown.

Comment: Yes, if you ***really want*** the views to not be in the hierarchy (that is, hidden isn't ok), then simply remove the two "unused" views with `.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: One last thing, do you think that this is the optimum way to do a generic UIView subclass that shows a type of an image?
Also, if you form it as an answer I would love to rep you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to remove the views from the hierarchy (as opposed to just hiding them), there are two "straightforward" ways to go about this:

1. When you tell your subclass to "init" itself for the "image type," just use `.removeFromSuperview()` on each of the two views you no longer want. Just make sure nothing is dependent on those views (constraints, value checking, etc).

or

2. Instead of adding the views in Interface Builder and referencing them with @IBOutlet, simply **add** only the desired object as a subview via code.

Offhand, I'm not sure either method would necessarily be "better" ... Method 1. is probably a little easier to get the objects where you want them (layout and other properties), but method 2. is probably a little more "light-weight" and will be easier to modify down the road.

Comment: By the way, can we optimize it like this:
Instead of adding each one, I would add one UIView IBOutlet to the xib.
At the setup code, I will check the parameter and initialize the necessary UIView subclass (i.e. as AnimatedImageView). Is this feasible?

Comment: I'd say that's just adding complexity, not optimizing it. I don't know what else is going on in your `MediaView` (bunch of labels? buttons? sliders? other stuff?), but if there *are* other elements, and you're having trouble with layout, you could add a "plain" UIView in design mode, assign it to an `@IBOutlet`, and then add `APNGImageView` as a subview to *that* view, pinning it to all four sides (for example).